# tar create: How to avoid to show the "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names" message in the terminal?

Tags: tar, options

About the `tar` command

If is executed the command:

```
tar -czf numbers.tar.gz numbers
```

The `numbers.tar.gz` file is created - from the `numbers` - in the current directory

But for **script purposes** - by testing - if is executed:

```
tar -czf ~/numbers.tar.gz /home/username/numbers
tar -czf /home/username/numbers.tar.gz /home/username/numbers
```

Both commands **work** as expected, but always appears the following message:

- "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names"

It happens because at least one path - in this case for both  have/include the `/` character. I know it is **not** an error, but being curious

**Question**

- How to avoid to show the "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names" message in the terminal?

I am assuming it is either an *info* or *warn* message and for **script purposes** is need it define the paths for the `tar.gz` to create and the source `directory` to compress - and I don't want see in the terminal that message. Is possible? with what option?

Comment: It is an warning message sent to `/dev/stderr` where error/warnings are sent (to screen), and can be redirected, so `tar -czf numbers.tar.gz numbers 2> /dev/null` will save your eyes from seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having absolute paths as archive members is a bad idea. That's why GNU `tar` actually removes the initial `/` by default (from archive member names and from hard link targets if any).

If you're happy for `tar` do that stripping but want to remove the warning, you can do the stripping by yourself:

```
tar -C / -czf ~/numbers.tar.gz home/username/numbers
```

Or:

```
tar -C /home/username -czf ~/numbers.tar.gz numbers
```

For the archive members to be `numbers/file` instead of `home/username/numbers/file`.

You can tell `tar` not to do the stripping with `--absolute-names` / `-P` in which case you'll get `/home/username/numbers/file` as archive members.

Upon extractions, most `tar` implementations will also strip that leading `/` by default as a safety measure. If you extract it from within the `/tmp/test` directory, the files will be extracted as `/tmp/test/home/username/numbers/file` whether they're stored in the archive as `home/username/numbers/file` or `/home/username/numbers/file`, unless you pass the `-P` / `--absolute-names` option again (though doing a `cd /` or pass a `-C /` would make more sense if you do want the paths to be interpreted as relative to the root, same as absolute paths).

Comment: I thought that the `tar` command by default internally understand and split the _path_ against the _filename_ and _directory_ - something similar as the `cp` or `mv` commands do - I mean, define the _source_ and _target_ paths as either _relative_ or _absolute_